# IE Changing .twbx file to .zip when downloading

Tags: internet-explorer, iis-7, mime-types

I am trying to create a link to let users download .twbx files. In Chrome, this works fine. In IE, the browser chagnes the extension to .zip when trying to download. The server is using IIS 7 and I added a MIME type for .twbx for application/octet-stream....this still is not resolving the issue. When I used Fiddler to monitor the click for the download, it does not show a content type. On a different web server where this link works correctly, Fiddler is showing the content type as text/plain.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. My SP admin changed the MIME type for .twbx and it now downloads those files as such. While I waiting for the MIME type to change I was able to create links with some javascript for the .twbx files so they would download as such.

Go to the SP library that houses your .twbx file and inspect the element using FF or Chrome. What you are looking for is the code for "Download a Copy" it should look like this:

`<span type="option" text="Download a Copy" onmenuclick="STSNavigate('https://www.....')" iconalttext="" id="ID_DownloadACopy"></span>`

All you need to do is change the onmenuclick to onclick and then obviously include the link to the .twbx file from your library. Once you have that link in SP you should be able to get the file to download as .twbx.